# Sealed Class - Why Remove the Public Constructor?

Tags: c#

I have a class, the stub of which is shown below. Code analysis gripes if I don't remove the public constructor. But I'm curious why this is necessary on a sealed class? The particular class shown below only contains static methods. Why would it be good practice to include a private constructor just to remove the public one?

```
    public sealed class ParseFile
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Remove the public constructor to satisfy CA1053.
        /// </summary>
        private ParseFile()
        {
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're not getting this warning because the class is sealed, but because it is (effectively) a static class.

A public constructor implies that the class has instance methods - classes that don't shouldn't advertise otherwise.

Answer (score 15):

If there's only static methods, declare it as a static class, and stop worrying about constructors.

```
public static class ParseFile 
{ 
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> If you have a class that only has
> shared methods, why do you need to
> create an instance of it?
>
> An example of a class with only shared
> methods, is the System.Math class. It
> has a private constructor, as it adds
> no benefit (and it makes no sense) for
> it to be createable.

Source: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vstscode/thread/8addbc70-f720-4d0b-85ce-2bdf52e32f77

The question is why should I make it private, but why should stay public. Always grant the minimum access it is required.

Answer (score 3):

Sealed is not the same as Static. A static class means that you cannot create an instance of a class with the new keyword. A sealed class means that you cannot create a class which inherits from it.

Comment: You may already know this, but `static` is C# sugar for declaring a `sealed abstract` class. :) The C# language specification adds the additional restriction that the type only contain static members due to the fact that instance members of a sealed abstract type would never be callable.

Comment: @280Z28 are you sure?? I've tried declaring a sealed abstract class and got a compile error saying that an abstract class cannot be sealed or static

Comment: @Pedro: Yes, it's similar to how you can't use the `System.Void` type in C# - you have to use `void` instead. I guess I should have said "C# syntax" instead of "C# sugar".

Comment: @280Z28: yeah, I read it further and understood what you meant.

Answer (score 2):

A class with all static method does never need a constructor as it is not instantiated with a new keyword. So you need no public constructor.